# PHP Is one value set and not another

Tags: php, isset, false-positive

I'm working on a truthy/falsy where I need to check 2 values, of which one may be null, the other 0. If integer vs string value same, they'd be the same.
The simplest I've been able to break it down is:

```
if($var1 == $var2) {// They may be the same
  if((isset($var1) && !isset($var2)) || (!isset($var1) && isset($var2))) { // Is one set, and not the other?
     return true; // As different as we'll allow
  }
  return false;   // Nope they're the same
}
return true;      // Definitely different
```

My question would be mainly, given the above code block, is there a simpler way to check if one value is set, and not the other?

EDIT: The reason I check for equality first, is that the value may pass 1 == 10 or 10 == '10', in which case, I don't need to check further, but if null == 0, this would pass and require further checking. I saw that I can pass multiple values to isset, which would work if I required both to be set or both not set, but if one is, and not the other, that's where I need to flag.

Comment: *If* both values are the same, you test whether one of them isn't set…!? Can you simplify your question to clearly tell us what values you expect and what the result should be?

Comment: _Small point which lots of people seem to miss/forget_ You can pass more than one value to `isset()`  and it will AND them to get the result. [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: @Riggs Very true, but not helpful in this case. :)

Comment: @deceze Agree'd, but I keep seeing this and felt the urge to void a little :)

Comment: The reason I check for equality first, is that the value may pass 1 == 10 or 10 == '10', in which case, I don't need to check further, but if null == 0, this would pass and require further checking. I saw that I can pass multiple values to isset, which would work if I required both to be set or both not set, but if one is, and not the other, that's where I need to flag.

Comment: That ^ belongs in the question as an edit.

Comment: First of all, do you actually need `isset` (if so, why), or just `=== null`?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Updated edit, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for equality *before* checking if they are set.

I'd recommend checking if they are set first.

If the PURE goal is to check if one is set and not the other, then:

```
return ( ( empty($var1) && ! empty($var2) ) || ( ! empty($var1) && empty($var2) );
```

Per comments, `isset` is the requirement, so this version:

```
return ( ( isset($var1) && ! isset($var2) ) || ( ! isset($var1) && isset($var2) );
```

And, props to @deceze to suggest an even simpler version:

```
return ( isset($var1) != isset($var2) );
```

Comment: Simplified: `return empty($var1) != empty($var2)`…

Comment: Thanks, this helped: isset($initial) != isset($final). 
empty() wasn't what I was looking for, but the comparison helped @deceze

Answer (score 2):

Using the null coalescing operator may come in handy...

```
return ($var1 ?? null) !== ($var2 ?? null);
```

Checks that they are not equal and at least one is defined and not null.

Comment: Note that this method is PHP 7+ exclusive.

Comment: @CodeWard 5.6 is EOL at the  end of the month, might want to upgrade if possible.  I don't know any OS vendors that will extend support for 5.6.